# Send input value to ajax in Laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-blade

I have a list of comments Now I Want to send reply to everyone,I used this code in input form:

```
 @foreach($comments as $comment)
        <div class="questions" dir="rtl">
            {{$comment->description}}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$comment->id}}" 
                     class="comment_id">
                    <button type="submit" style="float:right" 
                    class="send_answer"> send </button>
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input class="answer" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  @endforeach
```

Now I'm Using this code in ajax But I give undefined Error in Console:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.send_answer', function (event) {
            var comment_id = $(this).find('.comment_id').val();
            var answer = $(this).find('.answer').val();
            console.log(comment_id);
            console.log(answer);

        });
```

How I Can give Comment_id and send to ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `parent()` or `prev()` to get the `comment_id` in jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.send_answer', function (event) {
        var comment_id = $(this).parent().find('.comment_id').val();
        var answer = $(this).closest('.questions').find('.answer').val();
        console.log(comment_id);
        console.log(answer);
});
```

Comment: this code worked for comment_id but answer is empty or undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()`,`parent()` and indivisual element `id` and `class`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.send_answer', function (event) {
    var comment_id = $(this).closest('.questions').find('.comment_id').val();
    var answer = $(this).closest('.questions').find('.answer').val();
        console.log(comment_id);
        console.log(answer);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions" dir="rtl">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" value="121" 
                     class="comment_id">
                    <button type="submit" style="float:right" 
                    class="send_answer"> send </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input class="answer" type="text" value='answer' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```